# matplotlib 1.3.1 save figure in pdf does not work

Tags: python-2.7, matplotlib

I tried running this code to plot a simple scatter plot with the code:

```
plt.subplot(111)
plt.plot(x, y, linewidth=1.0)
plt.savefig('P_vs_time.pdf')
```

but I get the following error:

```
      Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "~/python/test.py", line 295, in <module>
      plt.savefig('P_vs_time.pdf', bbox_inches='tight')
    File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/pyplot.py", line 561, in savefig
      return fig.savefig(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/figure.py", line 1421, in savefig
      self.canvas.print_figure(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/backend_bases.py", line 2167, in print_figure
      **kwargs)
    File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/backends/backend_pdf.py", line 2358, in print_pdf
      file.close()
    File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/backends/backend_pdf.py", line 507, in close
      self.writeFonts()
    File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/backends/backend_pdf.py", line 607, in writeFonts
      fonts[Fx] = self.embedTTF(realpath, chars[1])
    File "/usr/lib/pymodules/python2.7/matplotlib/backends/backend_pdf.py", line 1008, in embedTTF
      ps_name = sfnt[(3,1,0x0409,6)].decode('utf-16be')
  KeyError: (3, 1, 1033, 6)
```

Why is this happening?

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is that you didn't add `plt.show()` after you created the plot. So try doing this:

```
    plt.subplot(111)
    plt.plot(x, y, linewidth=1.0)
    plt.show()
    plt.savefig('P_vs_time.pdf')
```